# ols and multiple regression model wth two variables

Tags: regression, correlation, least-squares

My model is as follows:
$y=b_1*X+b_2*\max(X,0)+u$

Will I have any problems with the variables $X$ and $\max(X,0)$, concerning any correlation issues?

Can I just apply the classic OLS methodology?

Comment: This question is very vague. If you are asking us how correlated your $X$ and $max(X, 0)$ will be, we obviously have no idea. If you think there will be many negative elements in $X$, then there is no problem to apply the OLS estimator directly. If not, then I suggest you regularise your problem.

Comment: The 36% of X are negative, so i have to regularise my problem i suppose !!

Comment: I would classify 36 % as much, but regularisation may help you anyway.

Comment: You could think of parametrizing the model differently (using a Dummy D that is 0 iff X is negative and D*X), but generally you don't have more troubles than let's say using X and its square.

Comment: I have also thought to use a dummy variable, but i want to know the exact value of y when the positive part of X is 0.01

Comment: @dimos: this would amount to setting D equal to 1 and X to 0.01. Note that you will never be able to predict the exact y value. OLS 'only' gives you its expected value.